# join table technique using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Guys on my database i have three tables containing data as shown on a link below.
 On tables **class and subjects**, *ssid and csid* are foreign key from  *members*.

I joining tables using left join as shown in model code shown below. 
when i echo *first_name, surname and class_name* for `John claudius` it appears three times while for `Alex massawe` it appear only once.
 but if i add information for `Alex massawe` result will displayed out as many times as information for `Alex massawe` 
that are within subjects. 
I need your help so that information given out will not be repeated if add information on tables **subjects** for a person whose name already in tables members.

### Tables within database

[my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5bw7.png)

members

sid           first_name          surname
a001        alex                          massawe
a002        John                        claudius

class

id             csid          class_name
01           a001          baby_class
02           a002          Class_one

subjects

id         ssid       subject_name
01        a002     Mathematics
02       a002      literature
03        a002    Communication skills

### codes

Models:

> function get_particular($sid){
>      $this->db->select('*');
>   $this->db->from('members m');
>  $this->db->join('subjects s',
>   'm.sid=s.ssid', 'left');
>  $this->db->join('class c',
>   'm.sid=c.csid', 'left');
>  $this->db->where('m.sid', $sid);
>   $query = $this->db->get();
>   return $query->result_array(); 
>       }

Controller:

> function particular($sid){
>      $sid=$this->uri->segment(3);
>   $this->load->model('names');
>
> $this->data["names"]=$this->names_rank->get_particular($sid);
>     $this->load->view("view/details", $this->data); 
>  }

view:

> foreach($names as $name)        {
>
> echo $name['sid'].' '. $name['first_name'].' '. $name['surname'].'
>   '.$name['class_name'];
>   }

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the loop - Changing your view

**From**

```
foreach($names as $name) {

echo $name['sid'].' '. $name['first_name'].' '. $name['surname'].' '.$name['class_name'];
}
```

**To**

```
echo $name['sid'].' '. $name['first_name'].' '. $name['surname'].' '.$name['class_name'];
```

or if you need the loop, then it should loop for each member and echo name. i.e
foreach $member echo $names

Answer (score 0):

Details from tables **members** (first_name and surname) and **class** (class_name)  are shown in view.
So remove the left join to **subjects** table from query. this join is the reason for  repeated records if there are more than one record for same member

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('members m');
$this->db->join('class c', 'm.sid=c.csid', 'left');
$this->db->where('m.sid', $sid);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```